Android Studio, could not find method compile for tflite
I am trying to run my flutter app in android studio on a virtual emulator. While trying to run the app by typing in 'flutter run' using the terminal, they gave this error message.
* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\tflite-1.1.2\android\build.gradle' line: 36

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':tflite'.
> Could not find method compile() for arguments [org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:+] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

So I went to the place where the error message showed, this is the entire code for build.gradle:
group 'sq.flutter.tflite'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'
    }
}

rootProject.allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
    }
    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }
//The codes below is where the error is
    dependencies {
        compile 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:+'//line 36
        compile 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-gpu:+'
    }
}


I have tried searching online for answers but have been unable to find solutions for this problem. This is my first time using Android Studio so any help would be much appreciated.
Some additional info:
The android studio version im using is Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Canary 9
As for java, this is the version im using:
java 18.0.2.1 2022-08-18
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 18.0.2.1+1-1)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 18.0.2.1+1-1, mixed mode, sharing)

That library you try to use it not compatible with the Gradle version you are using.
You need to either downgrade the Gradle version to something your dependency is compatible with, or use a newer version of the library that is compatible with your Gradle version.
If the latter is not possible as there is no newer version, then check whether that library is actually maintained and if not consider whether you really want to use it.
If it still is maintained, then you should report a bug about the Gradle version compatibility.
